# How do multiple save() calls interact in a grails/hibernate transaction?

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions

I am trying to create a new database object, save it, and check to see if the save succeeded. What is the right way to do this:

```
class Document {
    String externalId;

    static constraints {
        externalId(blank: false, unique: true);
    }        
}

def createDocuments(List<String> ids) {

    Document.withTransaction() {
        ids.each { String id ->
            new Document(externalId: id).save();
        }
    }

    // want to test here if transaction succeeded.
}
```

This transaction may fail because some other user may have created one of the documents at the same time. Thus while an instance is valid (i.e., its externalId is not blank) it may not be unique. But there is no way to tell without running the transaction.

What to do?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answers provided so far, here is the crux of my problem:

If I run a transaction that calls multiple saves, when do the saved objects become available to other hibernate sessions? Some possibilities:

1. When the `save` call returns
2. When the transaction is committed
3. Some other indeterminate time (presumably before #2)

If a `save` on one object fails because of a uniqueness constraint, and I roll back the transaction, will all other saves be rolled back too, even though they did not have a conflict? If not, what is the point of wrapping all this in a transaction?

Comment: .save returns the persisted object itself in case of successful save. You can us groovy truth on that. Have a look at [save](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) in grails docs.

Comment: I thought that the transaction will not commit until everything executes, so it wasn't clear to me that the save() would be able to detect duplicate violations. I don't want to specify `flush: true` on my saves because I want to optimize performance: I want to have one transaction for a bunch of documents.

Comment: Understandable. But validation here will be handled by hibernate even before flushing to database, so without using `flush: true` you should be able to validate it efficiently.

Comment: I don't see how it can validate uniqueness before committing the transaction.

Comment: That is the whole point in having an ORM persistence layer like Hibernate. When you say `unique: true` in constraints, while saving hibernate (session) would check if there is any other record with the same `externalId` present in persistence layer. If found, then hibernate save would throw a validation message back which is in the same session/transaction. Based on that validation message you can decide what you need to do.

Comment: The use case I am trying to figure out has two different requests and thus two different hibernate caches. The only connection (as far as I can tell) between the two caches is the database. Thus simply checking the cache to validate the object won't do; one has to check the database. But I don't want to check the database on every object creation; I want to batch them up since I am creating many objects in the same transaction. Does this make sense, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the object before actually saving to database.
Also you can use exception handling too, to rollback transaction in case.
General pattern that I follow in these type of scenarios is like,

```
DomainClass.withTransaction{ tx ->
   try{
       def ref = new DomainClass(...)
       if(ref.validate()){
           ref.save()
       }
        else{
           //throw some invalid instance 

        }

    }
    catch(e){
      tx.setRollbackOnly()
      log.error e
    }
}
```

Comment: As with @dmahapatro's example, this is not thread-safe, and doesn't seem to do anything that a save() followed by a null test doesn't do.

Comment: To clarify a bit, I could make this thread-safe by synchronizing the method, but that would introduce a huge performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It does make sense after reading [my favorite article](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/) for the n-th time.

Is `externalId` the primary key for `Document`? If yes, then the optimized approach to use here would be to check the `existence` of the document before saving it:

```
//Avoid duplication in the submission as well by using Set<String>
def createDocuments(Set<String> ids) { 
    Document.withTransaction {
        ids.each { String id ->
            //If `id` is not the primary key then use
            //if(!Document.findByExternalId(id)){}
            //This way you maintain the integrity of the Document.
            if(!Document.exists(id)){
                if(!new Document(externalId: id).save()){
                    //Validation failed on constraints. Handle them here
                }

                //You may not need to call save on each Document, 
                //unless you need to validate the constraints
                //as all of the Documents created will be automatically saved to 
                //cache and ultimately flushed to db by end of the session, which
                //is in this case exiting the action method.
            }
        }
    }

    // You do not need to test here if transaction succeeded.
}
```

Comment: Two points: the sequence `if(!Document.exists(id)) ... new Document(externalId: id).save()` is not atomic: another thread might also be trying to insert the same document at the same time, and both may pass the (not) existence test, but one of the transactions will not succeed. Second: the article you cite says "If you just create a new instance via the new keyword, then the object is not attached to the session until the save() method is called."

Comment: I edited the question (and the title) to focus more clearly on what I think is the crux of the issue I am facing.

Comment: @GeneGolovchinsky Have you tried testing that with a multi-threaded scenario to see how does it behave?

Comment: I tested using two threads saving the same documents using the save() method and it appears that save() will return null when a document instance was created by the other thread. But then I don't understand why I need a transaction. Hence the re-worded question.